Component.render is not a function
Estoy tratando de mostrar un endpoint en mi front que está hecho con Astrojs y sale este error:
    [ERROR] Component.render is not a function
  Stack trace:
    at C:\Users\User\Documents\Proyectos de programación\proyectoTurismoCaribe\eval at instantiateModule (file:\C:\Users\User\Documents\Proyectos%20de%20programaci%C3%B3n\proyectoTurismoCaribe\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-DEPSZ3SS.js:56234:28
    [...] See full stack trace in the browser, or rerun with --verbose.

Esto es lo que he intentado:
He tratado de instalar nuevamente vite, pero no ha funcionado.
Cambiar el nombre del archivo, pero tampoco ha funcionado.
Quisiera que me guiaran dado que no sé que es lo que pasa y busco en internet, chatGPT y no saben dar con la respuesta, tal vez sea algo sencillo, pero tengan en cuenta que apenas voy comenzando en este mundo, muchas gracias a quien pueda darme alguna orientación
Este es el código:
---
import Actividad from "../components/Actividades.jsx";
---

<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Actividades</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <Actividad departamento="Atlántico" ciudad="Barranquilla" />
    </body>
</html>

---
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.astro";
import Hero from '../components/Hero.astro'
import Destinos from '../components/Destinos.astro'
import Actividades from "../components/Actividades.astro";
---
<Layout title="Turismo en el Atlántico">
    <main>
        <Hero />
        <Destinos />
        <Actividades />
    </main>
</Layout>

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Actividades = ({ departamento, ciudad }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchTurismoData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4321/api/actividades/${departamento}/${ciudad}`);
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Información no encontrada');
                }
                const result = await response.json();
                setData(result);
            } catch (error) {
                setError(error.message);
            }
        };

        fetchTurismoData();
    }, [departamento, ciudad]);

    if (error) {
        return <p>{error}</p>;
    }

    if (!data) {
        return <p>Cargando...</p>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{ciudad}, {departamento}</h1>
            <ul>
                {data.map((item, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>
                        {Object.keys(item)[0]}: {Object.values(item)[0]}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Actividades;

